# How get column type by the object attribute in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have an AR object, say: `CreditCard`

`CreditCard` has `id` which is `@type=:integer` that comes from `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter::Column`. However how can I get a column type by the attribute.

So for example: `HomeLoan.column_id.type == :integer`

If that is possible that would be awesome

Answer (score 3):

```
CreditCard.columns.find{|x| x.name == "id" }.type
```

or...

```
CreditCard.columns_hash["id"].type
```

Comment: Well, I did this sort of thing... However I thought there should be a niftier way, no?

Comment: it is more semantically correct to do it via SomeClass.column_types["name"].type